# Error in Visual Studio Team Services CI after upgrading .NET Core from 1.X to 2.0 (NU1105)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, .net-core-2.0

After upgrading an ASP.NET Core app from .NET Core 1.X to 2.0, Visual Studio Team Services CI is failing on restore/build/test.

The error is

> error NU1105: Unable to find project information for '[Project Path]/Portal.csproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore.

The error occurs after VSTS tries building a test project e.g. Portal.Tests.csproj that references Portal.csproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Portal.csproj, you need to delete or comment out the following line:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="X.X.XXX" />
```

It seems to be causing issues with VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional note in case anyone has a problem with the .net publish command due to this issue.

After upgrading from .net 1.1 to 2.0 the upgrade wizard left the following lines in the csproj file which caused the publish stage of our build to fail.

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
</Target>
```

Removing the dotnet bundle line fixes the publish.

It appears that the bundling process has been built in to the build of web applications which means that there is no need for the additional pre-publish step that was included in .net 1.x.  All that is required is to add a dependency to BuildBundlerMinifier which then processes the directives in the bundleconfig.json file included in all default .net core 2.0 web applications

[image]

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BundleTest, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>
1>Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json
1>Bundler: Done processing bundleconfig.json
1>BundleTest -> C:\Source\Repos\BundleTest\BundleTest\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\BundleTest.dll
```

Comment: So VSTS will run dotnet bundle without having any tools or commands referenced in the .csproj file?

Comment: Thanks @Valuator.  You are quite correct I had not fully explained the change.  Updated the comments to provide more clarity.

Comment: You do not need to remove dotnet bundle line after upgrade. You just need to upgrade tooling version. <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.6.362" />